# Passing query parameters using Router.go in iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to pass query parameters in Router.go like below:

```
var filter = 'abc';
var path = Router.current() && Router.current().path;
Router.go(path, {query: {filter: filter}});
```

But this does not change the url, it stills loads current path without query string only. But if I add the query parameter manually to path like:

```
Router.go(path+'?filter='+filter);
```

this works fine. But since I am trying to load same page with some filtered data. So clicking filter button repeatedly appends the filter string again and again to path.

What is the correct way of passing query string using iron router?

Comment: can I get my answer accepted?

Answer (score 12):

Right there in the docs

```
Router.go('post.show', {_id: 1}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});
```

The above JavaScript will navigate to this url:

```
/post/1?q=s#hashFrag
```

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes

Answer (score 4):

The parameters are `Router.go(path, params, options)`. The query part should go in the `options` parameter, so try the following: `Router.go(path, {}, {query: {filter: 'filter='+filter}})`.

**EDIT**

Answer updated according to Robins comment below.

Comment: I tried this but page does not re load with query parameters

Comment: This answer is almost correct. query needs to be a string like `Router.go(path, {}, {query: "filter=filter"})`. From Iron Router source line 220 https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/lib/router_client.js

Comment: Hehe, a 5 times up voted answer, and it's wrong ;P But good catch, that should explain why it didn't worked for Aashu.

Answer (score 3):

I found that if your first parameter in Router.go is a path, instead of a template name, the query filter is not passed. Use a template name:

```
Router.go(templatename, {_id: 1}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});
```

Comment: Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var path = Router.current() && Router.current().route.originalPath;
```

That should give you the path without the query string attached.

Comment: Has changed to Router.current() && Router.current().route.url