# How to set querystring or parameters dynamically with iron-router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

*I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549494/passing-query-parameters-using-router-go-in-iron-router) on how to append/modify query parameters without duplicating, but I can't make it work.*

I have a page in my Meteor application that lists items and allows filtering. I would like the filtering to be URL-based, so every change to a filter should reflect in the URL.
I use iron-router to then update the subscription accordingly.

For some reason, I can't modify the querystring though. This code doesn't trigger any action if called from a `Template.templateName.events(...)`:

```
# valuePairs = ["foo=bar", "bar=foo"]    
newUrl = Router.current().route.path {}, { query: valuePairs.join('&') }
Router.go newUrl
```

But if I call `Router.go(newUrl)` from the commandline, the expected result happens, i.e. the URL updates.

Is there another, preferred method to modify the query?

If not, how can I make above code work?

**UPDATE** - I just found that after running the event, if I go back in my browser history I can see the correct URL. It looks like something (?) triggers another page load to go back to original page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just based on

> if I go back in my browser history I can see the correct URL

Do you suppress the actual link event? An `<a href='#'>` would flip flop you right back.

```js
Template.tempyTheTemplate.events({
    'click awesomeButton': function() {
        // URL stuff
        Router.go(magicURL);
        return false;  // <-- suppresses the event
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh, I had completely forgotten about this question. The same you proposed here was resolved on [GitHub](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/900#issuecomment-59673360) when I was still having the issue. Thank you anyways. And I (personally) find `event.preventDefault()` more readable/obvious, but that's just preferences.